# error after data migration

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2-migration-tool

now that the Magento mode is development, I get this error:

Element 'steps': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( default, stores, websites ).

The vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/config.xml does in fact have the first element 'steps':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_DataMigrationTool:etc/config.xsd">
    <steps mode="settings">
        <step title="Settings Step">
```

so my question is other than removing the data migration tool, why is this config tool's config.xml doing what Magento is not expecting?

*edit
To add a bit more information, on a different server when I go to run the data migration: 
php bin/magento migrate:data --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/config.xml

Here I do get the config.xml error.

```
[2019-12-10 04:21:39][INFO][mode: settings][stage: volume check][step: Stores Step]: Migration completed[xx@xx public_html]$ php bin/magento migrate:data --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/config.xml
Reset the current position of migration to start from the beginning

In Dom.php line 339:

  More than one node matching the query: /config/steps/step, Xml is: <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!--
  /**
   * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
   * See COPYING.txt for license details.
   */
  -->
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:M
  agento_DataMigrationTool:etc/config.xsd">
      <default>
        .....
```

I am not sure what is different to where I was able to migrate on one server but not able to on this server, will keep digging unless someone has some insight ?

**further edit

I am going through another fresh install following the same steps but have disabled the webserver so that no magento page gets hit and the migration seems to be working. On the other server I was able to get the migration to work before, I had an error with the .htaccess file which prevented magento doing anything after install from any web hits. I think this explains the difference, but not the underlying problem with the migration config.xml file.

I really must be doing something to cause this as I see no-one else having this problem. My migration map xml files are the ones that come with the migration tool, for the versions I am working with and they pass with only warnings of data type mismatches for some fields, and the migration does work. I will want to migrate delta's and not have to keep doing this, so would very much like to get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same problem and wondered about it.
The problem was, that the data-migration module was activated in the config.php of magento 2.
Then setup:upgrade uses the etc/config.xml of the data-migration tool, which causes the error.

Solution: Disable the DataMigrationTool module in the config.php. The migration tool still works, but magento 2 ignores it in the setup:upgrade process.

I thought there was an info at the tool itself to disable the module, but i cant find it anymore.

Comment: I had the same issue, and in my case had to additionally disable my custom migration module to get past the error.

`magento module:disable Magento_DataMigrationTool && magento module:disable YourCustom_MigrateModule`